# Currency converter is not working properly? please help?

Tags: fatal-error, currency-rates

website name: http://kopanaacreations.com/. Present we are using INR is the default currency.

When user select the currency as "Euro" it is changing, but value is not converting correctly.

Example if a product cost is 6000 Rs. When converting to Euro it has to show approximately as 85 Euros. But it showing as 2Euros. [Values are approximately i am giving here].

Answer (score 2):

on “System->Manage Currency Rates” and set rates for currencies you’ve chosen before. You can use Webservicex to import currency rates from Webservicex service.

Please check [image]

Please check

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/